# STM32 - two errors in turns during programming

Tags: stm32, swd

I'm trying to program STM32F107VCT6 via SWD and I'm constantly getting two errors in turns (literally):

- `Error: Connect failed, check config and cable connection`
- `Error: Flash driver function execute error`

  `Erase: [ 0%]`

By "in turns" I mean that when I click "Download Code To Flash" in CooCox CoIDE, I'm getting the first error, and after the second try, I'm getting the second one.

I have a PCB made from the same schematics with this model of STM32 and it works just fine. Changes between the old board and the new one are very insignificant.

I thought the problem may be in connecting NRST line, but everything is fine. I used 10k pull-up resistor, and the connections seem to be OK. Also, the crystal oscillator looked guilty, but I disconnected it to check if I could program STM32 on the internal oscillator, but it didn't help. All signals are connected correctly and all GNDs are connected together.

Could someone point out some possibilities why STM32 could behave like this? I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: You might try loading the SWCLK line with a resistor to ground, possibly only a few hundred ohms.  Of course you could have a bad chip, or a problematic firmware flashed.  Trying to connect under reset, or force the chip into bootloader mode may get SWD working.

Comment: The resistor didn't help (10k, I don't have anything smaller). Is 'a few hundred' absolutely necessary, or 10k should also work? Unfortunately I can't reconnect BOOT0 and BOOT1 pins, so I don't take bootloader mode into account. I tried with NRST disconnected and no effect.

Comment: I tend to use only a few hundred ohms, your 10k is well more than an order of magnitude higher.  And I was not speaking of disconnecting NRST but rather asserting it while initially establishing the SWD connection.  You may want to do that manually and use the ST gui to drive the SWD adapter (pretty much the *only* time I use that tool).

Comment: U tried to use this tool http://www.kamami.pl/published/publicdata/BTC10/attachments/SC/products_pictures/zl30prg_prg.jpg, but it doesn't even see the STM32 when everything is OK. Could you give a link to the tool you use?

Comment: I used ST's windows based SWD gui tool as they recommend for the discovery boards.  I end up finding a windows VM to run it in about once a year, so no, I don't remember what it is called.  (I have a hacked up and otherwise broken build of the open-source st-flash which sort of works as an alternative "unsticker", though that build won't actually program boards, so typically I use that to recover and then use a normal build of st-flash to program good code.)

Comment: I see. Anyway, thanks for your ideas. The problem is still open.

Comment: Is the board your own, or is it an eval board of some description?  If your own, did you include the various damping passives on the JTAG/SWD bus?  You might have more luck if you can convince OpenOCD (which I assume is what you're using for a debug tool with CooCox) to lower the SWD clock frequency.

Comment: @markt It's my board, designed from scratch. No, SWD lines go straight to the programmer and it worked this way on the previous, older board. Thanks, I'll try to lower the frequency, I'll let you know about the result.

Comment: @markt, no progress so far. I think the uC has to be resoldered, a similar thing happened yesterday and it helped. I'll let you know if it did this time, too.